# How to install the add ons called pgbackups using git command on git version 1.9.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

When I am trying to install pgbackups addons using the git command:

`heroku addons:add pgbackups`
It is showing the following error:

```
WARNING: `heroku addons:add` has been deprecated. Please use `heroku addons:create` instead.
 !    Couldn't find either the add-on service or the add-on plan of "pgbackups".
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

PG Backups as an add-on itself has been replaced with backup tooling built-in to the Heroku Postgres add-on.

Use `heroku pg:backups`

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups